# How do you join three or more tables in RethinkDB?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have three tables: `user`, `post`, `postVote`.

I want to join these tables together to construct a list of posts for the current session user. `vote` field of each post item in the result list will be different depending on who the current session user is and for each post item. Think of how reddit voting works.

I added a compound index of `['userId', 'postId']` as `userIdpostId` in `postVote` table for faster `eqJoin`.

Here are table schemas:

```
user {
  id: string
  name: string
}

post {
  id: string
  authorId: string
  title: string
}

postVote {
  id: string
  userId: string
  postId: string
  vote: number
}
```

Desired result:

```
[
  {
    id: string // post id
    authorId: string // author user id
    authorName: string // author user name
    title: string // post title
    vote: number // vote for this post by current session user
                 // default to 0, if no matching entry is found in postVote table. 
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this might do the trick.

```
r.table("postVotes")
    .eqJoin("authorId", r.table("users"))
    .eqJoin(r.row("left")("postId"), r.table("posts"))
    .map(function(doc){
        //...clean up doc as necessary...
    }).run()
```

In the end you should have a document with a `left` and `right` key at the top most layer, and then another `left` and `right` contained as the top most `left` value. Doing the `.map` at the end will allow you to clean it up to your desired JSON result.

This is a bit of an approximation since I don't have your dataset, but let me know if you have any questions.